# Trying to copy a TMenu to another TMenu

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

Some simple test code that tries to copy from one `TMainMenu` to another. I'm making context sensitive main-menus.

I've included the `cpp`, `h` and `dfm`, if you wish to recreate.

This code has 3 `TMainMenu`s setup, and 2 buttons. One button copies from `TMainMenu2` to `TMainMenu1`, the other button from `TMainMenu3` to `TMainMenu1`. What I'm finding is that the menus are being copied but seem to act like submenus on the MainForm.

Main file

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit2.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}

TMenuItem *CloneMenuItem(TMenuItem *Src)
{
    if (Src) {
        TMenuItem *mi = new TMenuItem(Src->Owner);
        mi->Caption = Src->Caption;
        mi->OnClick = Src->OnClick;
        mi->Tag = Src->Tag;
        mi->Checked = Src->Checked;
        mi->RadioItem = Src->RadioItem;
        for(int i = 0; i < Src->Count; i++) {
            TMenuItem *c = CloneMenuItem(Src->Items[i]);
            if (c)
                mi->Add(c);
        }
        return mi;
    }
    return 0;
}

void CopyMenu(TMenu *Dst, TMenu *Src)
{
    Dst->Items->Clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < Src->Items->Count; i++) {
        TMenuItem *mi = CloneMenuItem(&Src->Items[i]);
        Dst->Items->Add(mi);
    }
}

void CopyMenu(TMainMenu *Dst, TMenu *Src)
{
#ifdef debug
    // just to try and see wtf is going on. Gives exception?!?
    String s1,s2,s3,s4;

    for(int i = 0; i < Dst->Items->Count; i++) {
        s4 = s3; s3 = s2; s2 = s1;
        s1 = Dst->Items[i].Caption;
    }
#else
    Dst->Items->Clear();
#endif
    for(int i = 0; i < Src->Items->Count; i++) {
        TMenuItem *mi = CloneMenuItem(&Src->Items[i]);
        Dst->Items->Add(mi);
//      Dst->Items->Add(mi);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    CopyMenu(MainMenu1, MainMenu2);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    CopyMenu(MainMenu1, MainMenu3);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Header file

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef Unit2H
#define Unit2H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Menus.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm2 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TMainMenu *MainMenu1;
    TMainMenu *MainMenu2;
    TMenuItem *MainMenu11;
    TMenuItem *MainMenu1Sub11;
    TMenuItem *MainMenu1Sub21;
    TMainMenu *MainMenu3;
    TMenuItem *MainMenu21;
    TMenuItem *MainMenu2Sub11;
    TMenuItem *MainMenu2Sub21;
    TMenuItem *MainMenu31;
    TMenuItem *MainMenu3Sub11;
    TButton *Button1;
    TButton *Button2;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Button2Click(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm2(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm2 *Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

DFM file

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 345
  ClientWidth = 499
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -24
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  Menu = MainMenu1
  PixelsPerInch = 192
  TextHeight = 32
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 24
    Top = 160
    Width = 417
    Height = 50
    Margins.Left = 6
    Margins.Top = 6
    Margins.Right = 6
    Margins.Bottom = 6
    Caption = 'Set MainMenu to MainMenu2'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 24
    Top = 232
    Width = 417
    Height = 50
    Margins.Left = 6
    Margins.Top = 6
    Margins.Right = 6
    Margins.Bottom = 6
    Caption = 'Set MainMenu to MainMenu3'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
  object MainMenu1: TMainMenu
    Left = 48
    Top = 24
    object MainMenu11: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'MainMenu1'
      object MainMenu1Sub11: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'MainMenu1->Sub1'
      end
      object MainMenu1Sub21: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'MainMenu1->Sub2'
      end
    end
  end
  object MainMenu2: TMainMenu
    Left = 200
    Top = 24
    object MainMenu21: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'MainMenu2'
      object MainMenu2Sub11: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'MainMenu2->Sub1'
      end
      object MainMenu2Sub21: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'MainMenu2->Sub2'
      end
    end
  end
  object MainMenu3: TMainMenu
    Left = 360
    Top = 32
    object MainMenu31: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'MainMenu3'
      object MainMenu3Sub11: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'MainMenu3->Sub1'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `TMenuItem *mi = new TMenuItem(Src->Owner);` looks suspicious. Shouldn't the new menu item be owned by the new menu?

Comment: In both `CopyMenu()` overloads, `CloneMenuItem(&Src->Items[i])` is wrong. `Src` is a `TMenu` and `TMenu::Items` is NOT an array (ie, NOT indexable), so when `i > 0` then bad things happen due to you accessing invalid memory. You are confusing `TMenu::Items` with `TMenuItem::Items[]`, which IS an array (well, indexable, anyway). You need to use `CloneMenuItem(Src->Items->Items[i])` instead. Same issue with `Dst->Items[i]`, too.

Comment: Thanks Remy, that was it. You are the most useful person on the Internet!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code together, seems to works for me, with a little bit of extra work you could copy specific items from one main menu to another.

I have made the Button5 click event show whichever main menu on an MDI form to see the result but have not tested the click event but know it does work as I have done similar in other applications.

```
void __fastcall TForm6::Button4Click(TObject *Sender)
{
CopyToMenu(MainMenu1, MainMenu3);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CopyToMenu(TMainMenu *ItemSource, TMainMenu *ItemDestination)
{

ItemDestination->Items->Clear();

for(int i = 0; i < ItemSource->Items->Count; i++)
    {
    for(int j = 0; j < ItemSource->Items->Items[i]->Count; j++)
        {
        TMenuItem *item = new TMenuItem(ItemDestination);
        item->Caption = ItemSource->Items->Items[i]->Items[j]->Caption;
        item->OnClick = ItemSource->Items->Items[i]->Items[j]->OnClick;
        item->Checked = ItemSource->Items->Items[i]->Items[j]->Checked;
        ItemDestination->Items->Items[i]->Add(item);
        }
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm6::Button5Click(TObject *Sender)
{
// Menu is the Form menu property
if(Menu == MainMenu1 || Menu == MainMenu2)
   Menu = MainMenu3;
else
   Menu = MainMenu1;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

based on Remy Lebeau's answer, this is what works for me.

```
TMenuItem *CloneMenuItem(TMenuItem *Src)
{
    if (Src) {
    TMenuItem *mi = new TMenuItem(Src->Owner);
    mi->Caption = Src->Caption;
    mi->OnClick = Src->OnClick;
    mi->Tag = Src->Tag;
    mi->Checked = Src->Checked;
    mi->RadioItem = Src->RadioItem;
    for(int i=0;i<Src->Count;i++) {
        TMenuItem *c = CloneMenuItem(Src->Items[i]);
        if (c)
            mi->Add(c);
    }
    return mi;
    }
    return 0;
}

void CopyMenu(TMenu *Dst,const TMenu *Src)
{
    Dst->Items->Clear();
    for(int i=0;i<Src->Items->Count;i++)
        Dst->Items->Add(CloneMenuItem(Src->Items->Items[i]));
}
void CopyMenu(TMainMenu *Dst,const TMenu *Src)
{
    Dst->Items->Clear();
    for(int i=0;i<Src->Items->Count;i++)
        Dst->Items->Add(CloneMenuItem(Src->Items->Items[i]));
}
```